# Como llamar a un modal con mismo id desde distintos div? HTML Ajax

Tags: html, ajax, bootstrap-4, modal

Estoy llamando un modal desde un archivo html, pero necesito llamar dentro de distintos div del mismo html.

ejemplo, en mi index.html tengo muchisimos div, a ellos les aplico un id para que desde este div por medio del id llame al script que llama al modal, entiendo que el id en un html deberia ser unico, pero no se me ocurre mas bien de que otra forma poder hacer esto.

```
<div id="btnModal"><span>texto y contenido de mi primer div</span></div>
```

```
<div id="btnModal"><span>Texto y contenido de mi segundo div</span></div>
```

Mi Script para llamar al modal, el cual necesito tenerlo en otro.html

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(e) {
            $('#btnModal').click(function(){
                //LLamado a Modal
                $.post('modal.html', function(xx){
                    $('#tmpModal').html(xx)
                    //LLamado Modal
                    $('#modal22').modal('show')
                })
            })
        });
    </script>
```

y este es mi modal

```
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="modal22">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title">Detalles del Formulario</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: con el id `btnModal` en múltiples `divs`, quieres que abran tu modal??, si es asi, porque haces que btnModal sea una clase en vez de un ID y en los divs en vez de poner un ID colocas un `class="btnModal"` y en jQuery lo llamas con $(".btnModal")

Comment: si amigo, funciona asi como mencionas, se me habia ocurrido en la cabeza que utilizar clases seria buena idea, pero como no soy del todo experto usando ajax, no sabia como llamar a la clase, Muchisimas gracias.